# How can I use Link with a component and dynamic endpoint

Tags: next.js

How can I use Link with a component and dynamic endpoint, Would I be better using Router for this particular use case and if so, how would I implement it?

```
{rentals.map((rental, id) => (
          <Link key={id} href={`/rentals/${rental.id}`}>
            <RentalCard rental={rental} />
          </Link>
        ))}
```

Comment: What do you have inside `RentalCard`?

Comment: do you use "passHref" in Link ?

Comment: Well , I could put the contents on RentalCard within the link but I like everything to be clean and easy for others to read. No, I am not familiar with passHref

Comment: Already figured it out, Just wrapped Rentalcard with an empty a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the RentalCard Component in an empty A tag like so;

```
{rentals.map((rental, id) => (
            <Link key={id} href={`/rentals/${rental.id}`}>
              <a>
                <RentalCard rental={rental} />
              </a>
            </Link>
          ))}
```